# Common font on different devices' browsers

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

What is most common font on different desktop and mobile devices. I need my website texts have same look and size on different devices.
Since I need it for Arabic scripts, I can't use web fonts, because Arabic (right to left) web fonts are not rendering properly on all devices, yet.

Comment: If you want to be sure of a particular font, provide it. Look at [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts)

Comment: Your desire isn't going to be reached just from a font name.  Apple has 72dpi screens, Windows 96dpi, and mobile phones are all over the place.

Comment: @MikeW I can't, because I need it for for Arabic scripts.

Comment: I strongly suggest if you really want your UI to look a specific way to provide your own font. There is likely a big difference between "most common" (which is generally focused on making the Latin character set look nicely) and "fonts that render Arabic nicely". As an additional thing to watch out for, I've also seen issues where the same font renders fine in one browser but not another (on the same platform)...

Comment: Also adding to the difficulty is even within the same environment the page can render differently depending on the fonts installed. I once had some terribly ugly font installed on my system with a name that started with "Times", and on some web sites it took precedence over "Times New Roman". I can't remember the name of it now, but it was making web sites look horrendous for a while before I figured out that it was a problem on *my* end and finally located and removed the font.

Comment: Why is the question tagged with “responsive-design” and “web”? The assumption that “Arabic web fonts” don’t render properly is probably wrong. The title of the question is general, yet the body mentions “Arabic scripts”, which implies a crucial limitation on the choice of fonts. Oh, and texts won’t look the same on all devices, no matter what you do. Try to formulate an essentially more concrete and targeted question (and show what you have tried so far with web fonts and explain *how* that has failed).

Answer (score 1):

Even the same font will look differently on different devices, especially on mobile devices. The way it looks will be affected but the native rendering of fonts, and also by the default font size relative to the screen dimensions on each device. Finally, users are allowed to adjust font sizes on almost all devices, and they often do - especially on large PC monitors.

The only reliable solution is to use a responsive layout, which displays your content correctly regardless of the font size or content length.